# I want to make a simple alarm clock using tkinter but encountering some issues

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a simple alarm clock using Tkinter but encountering some issues -
So I made tried to make an alarm clock using Tkinter python
first, I made a simple digital clock the clock worked fine now i used a if condition to make the alarm clock here is the code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from time import strftime
root = Tk()
root.title("Digital Clock")
root.geometry("600x510")
label =  Label(root,font=('sans',80),background = "black",foreground = "red")
labl =  Label(root,text="Krishna made this ",font=('sans',20),background = "black",foreground = "red")
label.pack(anchor='center')
labl.pack(anchor="center")
def clock():
    tick = strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
    label.config(text = tick)
    label.after(1000,clock)
    if tick == "19:00:00 PM":
        print("Wake up")
clock()
mainloop()
```

It doesn't work infact it showed up some errors

```
 2425, in pack_configure
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-achor": must be -after, -anchor, -before, -expand, -fill, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, or -side
>>> & C:/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/Avishi-Krishna/Desktop/campk/Python LV.3/digital-clock.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/Avishi-Krishna/Desktop/campk/Python LV.3/digital-clock.py"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> & C:/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/Avishi-Krishna/Desktop/campk/Python LV.3/digital-clock.py"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/Avishi-Krishna/Desktop/campk/Python LV.3/digital-clock.py"
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please tell me how to fix it I am using Visual Studio Code with Python 3.10.2

Comment: The error message mentions a string, "achor". Do you have an "achor" anywhere in your real code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Let user select time. Just set to one minutes. For example right now the is 7.40 53. then select 7. 41.00 then press alarm.

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
import time


window = Tk()
window.title("Alarm Clock")
window.geometry("400x160")
window.config(bg="#922B21")
window.resizable(width=False,height=False)



def Alarm(set_alarm_timer):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        actual_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        cur_time = actual_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        cur_date = actual_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        msg="Current Time: "+str(cur_time)
        print(msg)
        if cur_time == set_alarm_timer:
            print(f'Hey! Wake up, Krishna Singh')
            break

def get_alarm_time():
    alarm_set_time = f"{hour.get()}:{min.get()}:{sec.get()}"
    Alarm(alarm_set_time)
          
time_format=Label(window, text= "Remember to set time in 24 hour format!", fg="white",bg="#922B21",font=("Arial",15)).place(x=20,y=120)
 
addTime = Label(window,text = "Hour     Min     Sec",font=60,fg="white",bg="black").place(x=210)
setYourAlarm = Label(window,text = "Set Time for Alarm: ",fg="white",bg="#922B21",relief="solid",font=("Helevetica",15,"bold")).place(x=10, y=40)
 
hour = StringVar()
min = StringVar()
sec = StringVar()
 
hourTime= Entry(window,textvariable=hour, bg="#48C9B0",width=4,font=(20)).place(x=210,y=40)
minTime= Entry(window,textvariable=min, bg="#48C9B0",width=4,font=(20)).place(x=270,y=40)
secTime = Entry(window,textvariable=sec, bg="#48C9B0",width=4,font=(20)).place(x=330, y=40)
 
submit = Button(window,text = "Set Your Alarm",fg="Black",bg="#D4AC0D",width = 15,command = get_alarm_time,font=(20)).place(x =100,y=80)
 
window.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]